# Random one in a Bidimensional Array of zeros

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to create an bidimensional array of zeros and generate a random one inside it. But when I compile it it fills the random column with ones. I saw the error is in the loop to write the map because if I put all the `for ( j = 0; j <= c; j++ )` outside and inside I change for `for (i = 0; i <= l; i++ )` instead of filling the column it will fill the line. Unfortunately though I don't know how to solve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
    int l = 20;
    int c = 20;
    int map[l][c];
    int i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r_colum;
    int r_line;

    r_coluna = rand() % c;
    r_linha = rand() % l;

    /* Create a map of 0 */
    for (i = 0; i <= l; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j <= c; j++ )
        {
            map[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("%d %d \n", r_colum, r_line); 
    map[r_linha][r_coluna] = 1;

    /* Write the map*/
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("%d ", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Incorrect Output: The 1 is supposed to be on line 16 column 4, not in all columns.

[image: The 1 is supposed to be on line 16 column 4, not in all columns.]

Comment: Your observations are inconsistent with the logic in your code, which looks correct.  Can you show us sample "incorrect" output?

Comment: I think the code you posted is out of date with what is generating this output.  Please compile, build, and run with the exact code you gave above.

Comment: You are still accessing out of bounds of the array, `for (i = 0; i <= l; i++ ) {` and the following line.

Comment: The output correspond to the code.

Comment: Sorry M.M didn't quite get what you meant.

Comment: Fix your out of bounds access and the program will work. `for (i = 0; i <= l; i++ )` should be `i<l` not `i<=l`. Same problem for `j` in that block.

Comment: Thanks Alan and M.M (now I got what you meant), now is working fine!

Comment: Where did `r_coluna` come from?? Shouldn't it be `r_colum` (same for line)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that David, i translated the code from Portuguese to english to put here and I forgot that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off eliminating the variable length array, and going with a simple `#define` (after fixing, the copy/paste errors `r_coluna` and `r_linha`). Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MSIZE 20

int main (void)
{
    int map[MSIZE][MSIZE] = {{0}};
    int i, j, r_colum, r_line;
    srand (time (NULL));

    r_colum = rand () % MSIZE;
    r_line = rand () % MSIZE;

    printf ("%d %d \n", r_colum, r_line);
    map[r_line][r_colum] = 1;

    /* Write the map */
    for (i = 0; i < MSIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < MSIZE; j++) {
            printf ("%d ", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example/Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arraymap
2 9
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```